# display top level site list item in a subsite

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have created a custom list on the top-level site (root site) and I would like to access it from a subsite. But so far I did not have any luck. I thought by using SPcontext.current.site.rootweb, I could access the list and iterate through the items of that list, but it does not work.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Regards,

SPcontext.Current.Site.Rootweb

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Web.Site;

foreach (SPList list in site.RootWeb.Lists)
{
    //Your code here.....
}
```

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for your reply. I will give it a try and let you know if it works. Cheers

Comment: Sure Man, Also please mark it as ans if it solves ur problem...Cheers

Comment: Problem solved. Using SPcontext.current.site.rootweb was correct. I had made a mistake somewhere else in the code that is why it was not working.

Answer (score 0):

To access a list or lists in the top level site via a subsite, 
use this:

```
SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb
```